# MySQL Batched Key Access - no benefit?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an existing query on MySQL that's taking 25 minutes to run on a new v5.6.14 server with SSD drives.

It's simply of the form:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM table a 
INNER JOIN table b
ON a.uid = b.uid;
```

There are 31 million rows in each table and there's a one-to-one relationship between uid on each.  Also, uid is the Primary Key of both tables.  The tables are 2k and 4k wide respectively with no columns wider than varchar(255).

I'm coming from a SQL Server background and would expect this query to run in seconds via a Merge Join.  I understand the MySQL has been limited to Nested Loops though, so I thought I'd try the new (5.6) Batched Key Access optimisation which together with Multi Range Read enhancements should make things faster.  However, this gives only a very marginal improvement - down to 24 minutes.

Explain shows that there's no temporary table or filesort used, and when BKA is enabled I can see:
| Using join buffer (Batched Key Access) |

Relevant optimser settings are:

```
optimizer_switch=mrr=on
optimizer_switch=mrr_cost_based=off
optimizer_switch=batched_key_access=on
join_buffer_size=<increased 100x from default>
read_rnd_buffer_size=<increased 100x from default>
```

Is there something I have missed?  Or is it simply because the SSDs are fast enough anyway and BKA is only of benefit for sequential reads from spinny disks?

Comment: remove a.* and b.*. Instead use the field names. * will select other information also when the query executed.

Comment: Thanks @Damodaran.  Yes, in actual fact I am selecting only the fields I need - but there are a couple of dozen fields - I showed it with *s in for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

With this sort of thing, it can be useful to get a lower bound estimate by selecting from just one of the tables first.

Depending on the language used, there may be some options to turn on or off buffering.  [percona](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/26/handling-of-big-parts-of-data/) recommends turning buffering off and explains how to do that when using php.  The mysql select syntax also allows you some control of caching.  Since you get the whole table you probably have no use for that, so turn that off as well.

If the library you're using has a the ability to use prepared statements that may help as well.

If you need to offload the processing time from the database, you might use mysqldump to dump those two tables and handle the joining offline in your own script.

There is probably a good reason that you have this data in two tables despite the 1:1 mapping, however if there is not then why not use one table?